# Is Khasan open to tourists?

Tags: russia, vladivostok

My travel guide has an article about Khasan: https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Khasan

The article makes it look like a potentially interesting travel destination, with a picture of the monument dedicated to the historic [Battle of Lake Khasan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Lake_Khasan) that happened there, and a mention of its unique geographical position:

[image]

[image]

The article does not contain any particular warning, just mentioning the train line in the "Get in" section.

**Question**: Is it really a place where tourists can go, for instance from Vladivostok?
I am sure the place is interesting in itself due to its uniqueness and battle history, but do they allow casual tourists to even enter the town? Is it just like another other minor Russian town, or on the opposite is it a kind of prohibited or permit-only zone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Russian Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)#%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C), Khasan is located in the [Border Security Zone of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Security_Zone_of_Russia) and you need a special permission from the Russian border service to visit the village.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a permission for visiting Khasan. I think you can get one in Vladivostok or Khabarovsk. If you are going there without permission, I think you can get an administrative fee

Comment: Vladivostok is big. Would you mind detailing where in Vladivostok the permission can be obtained?